# Transform an int to a char

Tags: templates, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-1.0, alphabet

I'd like to write the alphabet with a link for each letter. So I used templates but I don't how to make this letter I tried that but I had a normal mistake : (A decimal representation must imediately follow the &# in a character reference).

```
<xsl:template name="alphabet">
    <xsl:param name="iLetter"/>
    <xsl:if test="$iLetter &lt; 91">
        <a><xsl:attribute name="href">req.html?X_letter=&#<xsl:value-of select="$iLetter"/>;</xsl:attribute>&#<xsl:value-of select="$iLetter"/>;</xsl:attribute></a>
        <xsl:call-template name="alphabet">
            <xsl:with-param name="iLetter" select="number($iLetter)+1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

And I call this template ilke that:

```
<xsl:call-template name="alphabet">
        <xsl:with-param name="iLetter" select="number(65)"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

So, I'd like to obtain this result:

`A B C D ..... X Y Z` without ... of course :)

Comment: Good question, +1. Are you aware that the answer you accepted produces incorrect results?

Comment: Yes, I knew it but I corrected problems. Thank you for your +1 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Martin suggests it would be better to avoid using disable-output-escaping. You don't need it either, if you are would be satisfied with a plain ascii character instead of the numerical character reference. If so, you can use substring and a alphabet lookup-string like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:variable name="alphabet" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>

    <xsl:template name="alphabet"> 
        <xsl:param name="iLetter" select="65"/> 
        <xsl:if test="$iLetter &lt; 91"> 
            <a>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">req.html?X_letter=<xsl:value-of select="substring($alphabet, $iLetter - 64, 1)"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($alphabet, $iLetter - 64, 1)"/>
            </a> 
            <xsl:call-template name="alphabet"> 
                <xsl:with-param name="iLetter" select="number($iLetter)+1"/> 
            </xsl:call-template> 
        </xsl:if> 
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="alphabet"/> 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Cheers!

Comment: It is a very good idea! Thank you Martin Honnen and grtjn for your help. ;)

Comment: you just wrote a little mistake:

<xsl:value-of select="substring($alphabet, $iLetter, 1)"/>

and we must write that :

    <xsl:value-of select="substring($alphabet, $iLetter - 64, 1)"/>

There are no link without this substract

Answer (score 2):

The currently accepted answer is incorrect, because it doesn't produce correctly the text child of any `a` element.

**Here is a correct XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vAlpha" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:call-template name="alphabet"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="alphabet">
  <xsl:param name="pCode" select="65"/>
  <xsl:if test="not($pCode > 90)">
    <xsl:variable name="vChar" select=
     "substring($vAlpha, $pCode - 64, 1)"/>
    <a href="req.html?X_letter={$vChar}">
     <xsl:value-of select="$vChar"/>
    </a>
    <xsl:call-template name="alphabet">
      <xsl:with-param name="pCode" select="$pCode+1"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<a href="req.html?X_letter=A">A</a>
<a href="req.html?X_letter=B">B</a>
<a href="req.html?X_letter=C">C</a>
<a href="req.html?X_letter=D">D</a>
<a href="req.html?X_letter=E">E</a>
<a href="req.html?X_letter=F">F</a>
<a href="req.html?X_letter=G">G</a>
<a href="req.html?X_letter=H">H</a>
<a href="req.html?X_letter=I">I</a>
<a href="req.html?X_letter=J">J</a>
<a href="req.html?X_letter=K">K</a>
<a href="req.html?X_letter=L">L</a>
<a href="req.html?X_letter=M">M</a>
<a href="req.html?X_letter=N">N</a>
<a href="req.html?X_letter=O">O</a>
<a href="req.html?X_letter=P">P</a>
<a href="req.html?X_letter=Q">Q</a>
<a href="req.html?X_letter=R">R</a>
<a href="req.html?X_letter=S">S</a>
<a href="req.html?X_letter=T">T</a>
<a href="req.html?X_letter=U">U</a>
<a href="req.html?X_letter=V">V</a>
<a href="req.html?X_letter=W">W</a>
<a href="req.html?X_letter=X">X</a>
<a href="req.html?X_letter=Y">Y</a>
<a href="req.html?X_letter=Z">Z</a>
```

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="xs my"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xhtml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="pStart" as="xs:integer" select="65"/>
    <xsl:param name="pEnd" as="xs:integer" select="90"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vCodes" as="xs:integer*" select=
     "for $i in $pStart to $pEnd
       return $i
     "/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <html>
       <xsl:sequence select="my:alphabet()"/>
   </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:function name="my:alphabet" as="element()*">
  <xsl:for-each select="$vCodes">
    <xsl:variable name="vChar" select="codepoints-to-string(.)"/>
    <a href="req.html?X_letter={$vChar}">
     <xsl:sequence select="$vChar"/>
    </a>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the `a` element content you could disable output escaping as in

```
<a href="req.html?X_letter={$iLetter}">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&amp;#', $iLetter, ';')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</a>
```

That approach does not work within attribute nodes however so I left that part to pass the character code, not the character.

Also be warned that disable-output-escaping is an optional serialization feature that is not supported with all XSLT processors, for instance Firefox/Mozilla's built-in XSLT processor does not serialize the result tree but simply renders it so there the approach is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT 2.0 has the function `codepoints-to-string()`. With many XSLT 1.0 processors it should be easy enough to implement the same function as an extension function, though it will make your code dependent on that processor.